# Replace a value in a datatable by giving the column index

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Let `DT` be this datatable:

```
DT <- data.table(A=1:2, B=3:4)
```

We can replace the cell at row 2 of column B like this:

```
DT[2, `:=`(B=99)]
```

But I would like to replace by giving the *index* of the column, not its name. How?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, exactly ! (this is the expected answer). Thanks !

Comment: Same way as we do with dataframes? `DT[2, 2] <- 99`

Comment: Usually it's a bad idea in programming to use column indexes as you don't really know what is there and you won't get an error if you are modifying the wrong column.

Comment: Another (David's comment notwithstanding): `set(DT, 2, 2, 99)`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg In my situation this is the only way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a numeric index as a first parameter to `:=`. For example

```
DT[2, `:=`(2, 99)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use what @MrFlick commented or simply use this:
`DT[2,2] <- 99`

I don't know what's your preference for using that notation.