# Replace a column in a datatable by another column using dynamic indexing

Tags: r, indexing, dynamic, replace, data.table

Similar to [Replace a value in a datatable by giving the column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055018/replace-a-value-in-a-datatable-by-giving-the-column-index), 
I'd like to replace a column in a data.table by another column in the same data.table using column indexes only. (yes, withstanding the fact that this is generally not a good practice. In my case, it is the only way)

```
DT <- data.table(A=1:5, B=6:10, C=10:14)
```

and I want

```
DT[, A:=C]
```

but not using A and C. only their index numbers 1 and 3.

---

Edit: needed to elaborate a bit more on my use-case. I have multiple columns that need to be replaced by multiple other columns. The replacements are indicated by two columns in the data.table.

```
    DT <- data.table(A=1:5
                   , B=6:10
                   , C=10:14
                   , D=15:19
                   , E=20:24
                   , F=25:29
                   , G=c(1,2,NA,NA,NA)
                   , H=c(3,4,NA,NA,NA))

> DT
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1: 1  6 10 15 20 25  1  3  # --> column 1 (A) should be replaced by column 3 (C)
2: 2  7 11 16 21 26  2  4  # --> column 2 (B) should be replaced by column 4 (D)
3: 3  8 12 17 22 27 NA NA
4: 4  9 13 18 23 28 NA NA
5: 5 10 14 19 24 29 NA NA
```

Column G indicates the columns that need to be replaced. Column H indicates the columns that would replace those indicated in column G. Dealing with a data.table of a few thousand columns. and I know the names of columns H and G, so they don't need to be dynamic.

desired outputs:

```
> desired_output1:
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1: 10 15 10 15 20 25  1  3   #all of column A was replaced by column C
2: 11 16 11 16 21 26  2  4   #all of column B was replaced by column D
3: 12 17 12 17 22 27 NA NA
4: 13 18 13 18 23 28 NA NA
5: 14 19 14 19 24 29 NA NA

> desired_output2:
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1: 10  6 10 15 20 25  1  3   # col A for this row was replaced by col C
2:  2 16 11 16 21 26  2  4   # col B for this row was replaced by col D
3:  3  8 12 17 22 27  1  2
4:  4  9 13 18 23 28 NA NA
5:  5 10 14 19 24 29 NA NA
```

Comment: Not sure. Is this what you want? `DT[,3] <- DT[,1]`  ?

Comment: I think this `DT[,1] <- DT[,3]`

Comment: yes, yes, correct. Sorry I needed to elaborate more as I need it to be a bit more dynamic as it's multiple columns being replaced by multiple other columns, based on values of two columns . OK, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think there is really any elegant way to accomplish this other than looping the assign statement.  So basically you will need to use `DT[["G"]][i]` for the `ith` column to be replaced and then `DT[["H"]][i]` for the replacement column using list notation. In `data.table` you can refer to the column to be replaced by a number but to get the replacement values you will need to use `DT[[DT[["H"]][i]]]` which for `i=1` would be `DT[[3]]`. Putting everything together inside an lapply loop would give you the following:

```
lapply(seq_along(na.omit(DT[["G"]])),function(i) DT[,DT[["G"]][i]:=DT[[DT[["H"]][i]]]])
```

Since columns G and H will either both contain values or both be NA you can just choose one for the index in lapply in which I chose G. However, make sure that the NA values are at the end of the columns or the `seq_along` will give you bad indices when executing the loop. I assume based on your description that this will be the case.

Since you really don't care about the list produced by the `lapply` but only using it as a more efficient `for` loop you can suppress the output to the console (which may get annoying if you have thousands of columns to change) by wrapping the above with an invisible if you wish:

```
invisible(lapply(seq_along(na.omit(DT[["G"]])),function(i) DT[,DT[["G"]][i]:=DT[[DT[["H"]][i]]]]))
```

Hope this helps some!

Comment: This produces the correct data.table (desired output1), except that the output is not one data.table, it is a list of multiple identical data.tables (the list is as large as the number of replacements that were done.) This would create memory issue.

Comment: Yes you are correct if you assign the above code to an R object but remember with data.tables you do not need to assign the lapply to an R object. The loop should be at least as memory efficient as a for loop but in R, lapply loops execute more efficiently. That is why I say to add an invisible so you do not see the output to the console. If you assign the code to an R object you will not see the output to the console but you will be saving a large list to your memory.